# windows phone refuses to use the application cache

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, application-cache

I have an offline first web app https://onsite.kctrust.co.uk which uses the application cache and works perfectly on all browsers (IE10+) and on ios and android. The problem is Windows phone 8.1 refuses to use the cache. It will load from the network every time, even though it actually downloads and stores the correct assets, it just dosent seem to use them and goes to the network every time.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm not really sure what if any code changes i can make as it seems to be the phone and it works everywhere else. The manifest looks fine https://onsite.kctrust.co.uk/app.cache and all of the correct events fire on the client as evidenced by the update progress we have. If you go there on a Windows phone 8.1 though every time you request the home / login page it downloads the cache again and it just wont work in aeroplane mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Out of security issues Microsoft won't save sites deliverd through HTTPS.

I ran into the same issue and found a warning in the console.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn265017(v=vs.85).aspx

If you allow your Page to be accessible via HTTP it will use your application cache again.